# Rsync disregard double quotes in script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, backup, rsync

When the varialble `"$exclude_list"` is called as parammeter, rsync disregard double quotes and somehow include the home folder even that isn't mentioned in the script. I try to wrap it up in `"${exclude_list}"`, but that did't help eaither.

Displaing the content of the variable before using it in combination with `rsync`, shows that it is correct.

Another strange thing is that when I do `echo rsync ...` the output is correct and there is no errors.

Part of the problematic bash script:

```
    echo "$exclude_list"
    rsync -av --dry-run "$exclude_list" "$src" "$dest" >> /var/log/rsync.log || {
      sendmail "Error: rsync failed for folder $src."; exit 1; }
```

Output:

```
   --exclude=lost+found
   rsync: [sender] link_stat "/home/user/ --exclude=lost+found" failed: No such file or 
   directory (2)
   rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at 
   main.c(1333) [sender=3.2.3]
```

Here is the MCVE:

```
#!/bin/bash

# List of source folders
SRC_FOLDERS=(
  [0]="/mnt/load-1/"
  [1]="/mnt/load-2/"
)

# List of backup folders
DEST_FOLDERS=(
  [0]="/mnt/load-1-b/"
  [1]="/mnt/load-2-b/"
)

# List of folders to exclude during backup
EXCLUDE_FOLDERS=(
  "lost+found"
  "lost-found"
)

  # Form the exclude list for rsync
  for exclude_folder in "${EXCLUDE_FOLDERS[@]}"; do
    exclude_list="$exclude_list --exclude=$exclude_folder"
  done

# Loop through each folder pair
for i in "${!SRC_FOLDERS[@]}"; do
  src=${SRC_FOLDERS[$i]}
  dest=${DEST_FOLDERS[$i]}

    rsync -av --dry-run "$exclude_list" "$src" "$dest"

done
```

Comment: It seems to me that the problem lies in `$src`.

Comment: `echo rsync ...` won't show you which spaces separate arguments and which spaces are *within* arguments.  `printf '<%s>\n' rsync ...` is way better.

Comment: I try `printf '<%s>\n' rsync ... ` the result is correct as with `echo`. No errors and rsync read the variable as it is expected. I found another interesting behavior, when I remove the double qoutes, rsync also behaives as is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in

> ```
> for exclude_folder in "${EXCLUDE_FOLDERS[@]}"; do
>   exclude_list="$exclude_list --exclude=$exclude_folder"
> done
> ```

You iterate over an array `EXCLUDE_FOLDERS` and create a non-array variable `exclude_list` from it. When it's later referred to as `"$exclude_list"`, the shell expands it to a single word.

Before the `for` loop `exclude_list` is empty. The first assignment inside the loop makes the variable start with  `--exclude…`. Note the leading space. Because of this space `rsync` does not recognize this word as an option; it recognizes it as a *relative path*. I think your current working directory is `/home/user/`. The absolute path is therefore `/home/user/ --exclude=…`, such file does not exist, this is what the error states.

Even if the leading space wasn't there and `exclude_list` was created somehow as `--exclude=… --exclude=…`, it would still be wrong. `"$exclude_list"` always expands to a single word. You want each `--exclude=…` to be a separate argument to `rsync`.

Not quoting `$exclude_list` may kinda work, it's a poor solution though; e.g. [it will (or may) fail if elements of `EXCLUDE_FOLDERS` contain spaces, tabs or newlines (or wildcards that trigger globbing)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).

Please read [*How can we run a command stored in a variable?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/108618) In Bash it's often best to use an array. Make `exclude_list` an array:

```
for exclude_folder in "${EXCLUDE_FOLDERS[@]}"; do
  exclude_list+=("--exclude=$exclude_folder")
done
```

Then in the invocation of `rsync` use `"${exclude_list[@]}"`.